# Laptop keeps switching between being plugged in and not plugged in with external battery

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life, charging, charger

When I have my external battery hooked up to my laptop, it shows as being "plugged in, not charging" for a few minutes but then after about 10 minutes or so, it switches between being plugged in and not plugged in every 3 seconds or so which causes tremendous slowdown when watching movies when I need to use my external battery. Is it a problem of not getting the right current/voltage from the external battery? I tried all of the adapters with it and this was the only one that seemed to work at all.

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: Windows 10, upgraded from Windows 7

Comment: I have suddenly started experiencing this exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure remotely what is the reason (the one you gave seems probable), but I think you can workaround this problem and avoid slowdowns by entering Power Management options and choosing the High Performance power plan while the laptop is unplugged.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this already, but the fact that the computer keeps switching between the two so quickly is what causes it to slow down. Both unplugged and plugged in are on High Performance.